# Jquery mobile google maps client current location

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

i am using google maps with jquery mobile 
i want to add user  current location .i am using google maps.Show current location is google maps property but in my project ( [here is my project link :](http://teknonova.com/Map/Home/Index1)) i can't see show current location icon what should i do?

you can see show my location icon in google maps : [in here](https://maps.google.com/)